# Android ; PreferenceFragment language is not the same as the app

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments

Im develooping an app that will handle later language change from  preference but now my problem that my app will use phone locale (french in my case) but my R.xml.settings_prefs language is in english i have all my strings translated

```
strings.xml
values-fr/strings.xml
values-en/strings.xml
```

Here is a snap from my codes

SettingsActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    // Display the fragment as the main content.
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingsFragment())
    .commit();
}
```

SettingsFragment.java

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_prefs);

}
```

activity_settings.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What im doing wrong ??

Thanks for help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is exactly what you mentioned; "my app will use phone locale". Since you haven't specifically set another `Locale`, it will use the default one. To fix this you can add the following code in `onCreate` in `SettingsActivity`, before starting the fragment:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Using the en_US locale should be foolproof, since it must always be available. ("locale data is not necessarily available for any of the locales pre-defined as constants in this class except for en_US, which is the only locale Java guarantees is always available" [source: Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html)).

Comment: Thanks !! I figure it out and your right i used the same code as you metionned in my application and it did the thing :)